# Add the value of previous row with the current row and to retain the value of previous row while adding

Tags: r

In R I have a dataframe D1. It contain column "ID"and "Case". ID has duplicate values and case contain "NA" & "Up".

```
D1

ID case 
aa NA   
aa NA    
aa Up    
aa NA    
cc NA    
cc NA    
dd NA    
dd NA    
dd Up    
dd NA    
dd NA    
dd NA    
ee NA    
ee NA    
ee NA    
ff up    
ff NA    
gg NA
```

So my requirement is to create a new column 'Deep', where I want to:

1. Create a new column 'Deep' which contain value as 0.
2. secondly, Identify the first observation of ID for each group and assign it as 0 under 'Deep' column. 
    for example the first 'aa' will always be '0'.
    Although it will not effect the view of 'Deep' column as it still deep 
    column as 0 value.
3. Thirdly, Identify the value 'Up' from 'case' column and add as 1 to  it.
   so,  when case== up, then deep+1, so the output will be Deep = 1.
4. Fourthly,  Retain the value created by logic 'case == 'Up' i.e is '1' and add 1 to it till the same 'Id' is present.
   so all the value with same 'Id' after the case == 'Up', will add previous row value + 1 id deep = 2 and so on.

Note that, with every change in the ID the new value under 'Deep' will become 0.

Below is the output I want

```
ID case deep
aa NA    0
aa NA    0
aa Up    1
aa NA    2
cc NN    0
cc NN    0
dd NA    0
dd NA    0
dd Up    1
dd NA    2
dd NA    3
dd NA    4
ee NA    0
ee NA    0
ee NA    0
ff up    1
ff NA    2
gg NA    0
```

Here you can see a new column is created with 'Deep'.

1. First occurrence of any new id is equal to 0.
2. Value for the case == upper will be 1, followed by all the value with add to 1 till the id is not change or different ID is not found.
3. when new id is found, and the case is also upper, then in the situation the Deep will have value of 1 as in the eg of 'ff' where value is 1.

Please help me on this

Comment: `dplyr::group_by()` and a new conditional column with `cumsum()` should do the trick. Search for that, you should find plenty of examples.

Answer (score 3):

We group by 'ID', get the cumulative sum of logical vector created with `str_detect` and wrap with cumulative sum to add the 1 values

```
library(tidyverse)
D1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(deep = cumsum(cumsum(str_detect(case, "[Uu]p") & !is.na(case))))
# A tibble: 18 x 3
# Groups:   ID [6]
#   ID    case   deep
#   <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1 aa    <NA>      0
# 2 aa    <NA>      0
# 3 aa    Up        1
# 4 aa    <NA>      2
# 5 cc    <NA>      0
# 6 cc    <NA>      0
# 7 dd    <NA>      0
# 8 dd    <NA>      0
# 9 dd    Up        1
#10 dd    <NA>      2
#11 dd    <NA>      3
#12 dd    <NA>      4
#13 ee    <NA>      0
#14 ee    <NA>      0
#15 ee    <NA>      0
#16 ff    up        1
#17 ff    <NA>      2
#18 gg    <NA>      0
```

#### data

```
D1 <- structure(list(ID = c("aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "cc", "cc", "dd", 
 "dd", "dd", "dd", "dd", "dd", "ee", "ee", "ee", "ff", "ff", "gg"
 ), case = c(NA, NA, "Up", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Up", NA, NA, NA, 
 NA, NA, NA, "up", NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -18L))
```

Comment: thank you, It works fine, except when ID change it still do cumulative sum, although requrement is to make it zero example for 'ff'

Comment: @Vish  If you don't have a group by, then you can remove it

Answer (score 1):

Here is something in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(D1)
D1[, 
   deep := {
     tmp <- grep("up", case, ignore.case = TRUE)[1]
     if (is.na(tmp)) rep(0L, .N) else c(rep(0L, tmp-1L), seq_len(.N - tmp + 1L))
   } , 
   by = ID]

      ID case deep
 1: aa <NA>    0
 2: aa <NA>    0
 3: aa   Up    1
 4: aa <NA>    2
 5: cc <NA>    0
 6: cc <NA>    0
 7: dd <NA>    0
 8: dd <NA>    0
 9: dd   Up    1
10: dd <NA>    2
11: dd <NA>    3
12: dd <NA>    4
13: ee <NA>    0
14: ee <NA>    0
15: ee <NA>    0
16: ff   up    1
17: ff <NA>    2
18: gg <NA>    0
```

**Data**

```
D1 <- data.frame(
  ID = c("aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "cc", "cc", "dd", "dd", "dd", "dd", "dd", 
         "dd", "ee", "ee", "ee", "ff", "ff", "gg"), 
  case = c(NA, NA, "Up", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Up", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
           "up", NA, NA) 
)
```